USB-C Splitter for external SSD enclosure
I just got myself an external enclosure for 2 x NVME SSDs.
Got it from AliExpress and from the description and the pictures I was expecting it to have only one USB port. However, it seems it has 2 ports, one for each SSD (basically it's a case with 2 SSD racks).
So I was wondering if it is possible to get a splitter (although not sure the splitter is the right word here). Basically I want something like the image bellow but with USB-C.

The thing is, I couldn't really find many options so I am wondering if what I want is even possible.
Is it? Any recommendations? Maybe I am not searching for the right thing?
LE: Basically there are 2 adapters in one enclosure.



There are cables 'like' it, but its male to female splitting. You'd then have to connect cables in the female ends and those to your enclosure.  Not sure how power and data delivery would be like on a Y-cable solution. Why not get a small USB-C hub instead ?

Got a link? NVMe to USB smells off to me, since you need to convert from PCIe to USB, which sounds potentially complicated

Do you have any image link or specs of the product you bought ?

@JourneymanGeek Link for the product? Sure. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005664167001.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.11.93001802ugxppv
The product works just fine. It's just that is has 2 USB ports, one for each SSD.

@1NN Sure. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005664167001.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.11.93001802ugxppv

A splitter will not work, you will need a hub as the two drives work independently one from the other. Also, I don't think you'll find any splitter which supports USB 3.0 upwards, it's just not something which the USB protocol could foresee: you need a chip somewhere which will handle the USB protocol.

@JourneymanGeek: USB enclosures for NVMe definitely exist – I have one for USB3.x – it needs more complexity than "USB to SATA" of course, since it has to have its own PCIe host controller and all that, and it accordingly costs more than a SATA one (haven't even seen a dual SATA/NVMe yet), but the protocol translation is not an impossible thing as long as you only need the basics like read/write.

@1NN Thanks for the info. A hub kinda beats the purpose for me. Besides, I have a hub laying around somewhere. It's not a big issue anyway, it's just a convenience thing since some laptops don't have 2 USB port close to each other.

Can you post both the specs of the enclosure for 2 x NVME SSDs and a pic of its connectors?

@RobbieGoodwin I added the pics to the original post. The specs should be in the link above.

You can get USB splitter cables, but they're power-only.   I have some to power my desktop blinkenlights.   For data connections, you need a hub.

USB splitters aren’t a thing. If you don’t have enough USB ports, you need a USB Hub. But really if at all possible you should be using two USB ports on your PC/laptop.
Using a bus-powered hub could result in the SSDs not getting enough power.

That's what I was afraid of and didn't wanna but what I found.

Fundamentally, it's almost impossible to split a data cable of any type.  Doing so is like making a traffic intersection in total darkness.  I will not say absolutely because I have seen 10-BaseT where some electrician did it and it actually made an approximation of working.  The machines behind the split were glitchy (and corrupted data due to a machine mishandling the errors) but could power up and operate an entirely network-based application.

There's probably a cable-shaped hub out there if you really want that form factor.

In fact, that's probably why the manufacturer made 2 sockets in the enclosure -- so that it would drive power from 2 USB ports rather than one, and the SSDs would not be constrained by a single USB channel's throughput, either. External HDD enclosures sometimes ship with a "reverse splitter" -- you are supposed to connect it to 2 host USB ports so that the HDD would get enough power.

@LorenPechtel no one does that today (well, no one that's sane...), but the original design for Ethernet is basically a single long shared cable which is split out (or tapped into) by each workstation - I'm not sure how robust CSMA/CD implementations are today and this method is long deprecated, but in theory it should still work...

@MaciejStachowski Yes, but that was with basically just the center of a thick coaxial cable. Modern twisted pair ethernet needs either 4 or 8 wires that are (essentially) running parallel. Very different electrically, even if nominally the same as far as protocol.

@MaciejStachowski I wasn't referring to a coax installation, this was standard 8-wire cable.  Best guess is that since neither machine had any business with the other that nobody would have noticed they couldn't talk, both could talk to any machine not on their hacked wire.  They would never notice if they stomped on each other but the network protocols were enough to almost always save the situation.
